# Generate dynamic columns for JQGrid using json data

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

I have comma separated values in the form as shown below:

```
["Error","UserId","Username","EmailAddress","TitleId","FirstName","Surname","IsActive","PasswordEncoded","UserGroupId","UserLocationId","IsTeamLeader","TeamLeaderUserId","BadLoginCount","LastLoggedInDate","PasswordLastUpdatedDate","WebServiceHashKey","CustomerId","IsSalesRep","ManagerFirstName","ManagerLastName","ManagerEmail","TeamLeaderUpdatedDate","IsPushedToReporting"]
```

These values are the name of my columns, that i have to display in my JQGrid, so i am using the following code to generate my columns:

```
var splitCols = JSON.parse(cols);
var colM = splitCols.each(splitCols, function (a,b) {
    JSON.parse('[{"name": "' + b + '"}]');
});
```

`variable cols` consists of my all of the column names, the comma separated as i have shown above.

So, my whole and soul concern is to generate the columns like:

```
{name: 'UserId'}, {name: 'UserName'}
```

Can anyone help me to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as below:

```
var colmns = [];
$.each(cols, function (a, b) {
    var obj = {};
    obj["name"] = b;
    colmns.push(obj);
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(cols));
```

---

Here `console.log()` outputs something like this:

```
[{"name":"Error"},{"name":"UserId"},{"name":"Username"},.....]
```

#### [Checkout the jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/G3fkT/)

Comment: thanks again but i dnt know what the mess it has created for me but it shows like this: `[{"name":"["},{"name":"\""},{"name":"E"},{"name":"r"},{"name":"r"},{"name":"o"},{"name":"r"},{"name":"\""},{"name":","},{"name":"\""},{"name":"U"}`, looks like every single chararter is broken down. please suggest something for this

Comment: thanks i fixed it, i have to fixed parse the json :) glad u helped me again

Comment: No prob at all! This is what i like to do here at SO. Glad this helped you.